# Managing C dependencies with DUB

Tags: d, dub

I was testing DUB and I wanted to install derelcitsdl2 with

```
"dependencies": {
   "derelict-sdl2": ">=1.2.10"
}
```

But it immediately throws an runtime error when I run it. It tells me that it can't find the *.so files.

When I build a cross platform project I don't want to be dependent on global system packages like that and this will most likely be a problem on Windows.

Is it possible to run buildscripts with DUB?

Something that could look like this

```
"dependencies": {
   "derelict-sdl2": ">=1.2.10"
}
"c-dependency-sdl":{
   git clone sdllink && cd sdl && cmake . && make && make install clib
 }
```

I didn't find an information on the DUB website which tells me that is is most likely not possible.

How do you build your projects for different platforms?

Do I need to write .sh / .bat scripts for this? How would I specify the local search path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, dub does not handle the installation of non-dub dependencies. You can describe system library requirements with the `systemDependencies` entry, which will be "visible on the registry and will be displayed in case of linker errors", but they will not be installed automatically.

You could use `preGenerateCommands` or `preBuildCommands` to execute shell commands like you described above. I would put the install scripts in .sh/.bat scripts like you described above (so they are useable for non-dub users), and then place something like this in `dub.json`:

```
"preGenerateCommands-posix":   [ "./setup.sh"  ],
"preGenerateCommands-windows": [ "./setup.bat" ]
```

On linux, I would typically assume the necessary `.so` files are available on the standard search path (or available for install through a package manager), especially for something common like sdl.

As far as specifying search path, I just use `lflags`:

```
"lflags": [ "-L./ext/sdl/lib" ] (or wherever the local libs are)
```

Sources: [DUB Package Format](http://code.dlang.org/package-format)

Full Disclosure: I haven't actually tried using `preGenerateCommands`, but it sounds like what you need.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I turn this problem around and use make/gmake to drive the top-level build. This handles the C/C++ dependencies (which in my case get installed into /usr/local/lib and /usr/local/include) and uses Dub to build the D-language parts (referencing the dependency path as lflags in dub.json).